# Batching separate prepared npgsql commands

Tags: npgsql

Say you have three prepared NpgsqlCommands. Because they must be executed separatedly. But sometimes two or all three must be executed at once (well, one after the other).

Is there a way to batch and reuse these previously prepared commands using a single roundtrip to the server? (goal is to minimize latency)

Now I use a fourth command and semicolon separate a copy of the original three commands, and prepare this -- but I assume this will use more resources at the server, and more SQL parsing at the npgsql client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npgsql supports batching through including several statements in your `CommandText`, separated by semicolons. These are executed in a single network roundtrip, and can also be prepared:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ...; UPDATE ...";
cmd.Prepare();
```

Internally, Npgsql splits such commands on semicolons and prepares each statement separately (PostgreSQL does not actually recognize batches, only individual statements). In addition, Npgsql manages prepared statements on a statement-by-statement level, and knows to reuse already-existing statements. This means that if you prepare two commands which contain the same statements, those statements will share the same server-side prepared statement resource.

Comment: My current "separate" already-existing prepared commands all have a parameter with the name "@pkey" -- when executing two of them in a batch, each @pkey might need its own unique value. I believe a batched command has only one set of parameters? In this scenario, would I have to give my original three commands unique names for "@pkey" for getting reused prepared statements and unqiue parameter values for each? In other words do parameter names influence the mechanism of reusing an already-existing statement? Thanks for your insights.

Comment: No, parameter names don't influence anything. Under the hood, PostgreSQL actually doesn't support parameter names, only positional placeholders: $1, $2. Since in ADO.NET the standard is named placeholders, Npgsql parses your SQL and replaces the named placeholders (@pkey) with positional ones ($1), and the prepared statement cache only kicks in after that; so for the purposes of prepared statement caching only the versio processed version with the positional placeholders matters.

Comment: Examining the protocol with Wireshark isa great way to really understand what's going on - you can see the actuall actual SQL that Npgsql send to PostgreSQL, as well as which statements are prepared and which aren't, and which prepared statement name is used (which indicates caching and determined how many sever-side objects are in use).