# Preparing statements and batching in npgsql

Tags: npgsql

The `Simple Preparation` example in the docs (https://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html#simple-preparation) shows an example where parameters are set after the command is prepared.

```cs
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(...);
cmd.Parameters.Add("param", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
cmd.Prepare();
// Set parameters
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
// And so on
```

Questions

1. How are the parameters set?
2. Is it possible to use `AddWithValue` instead of `Add` if the `AddWithValue(String, NpgsqlDbType, Object)` method which specifies `NpgsqlDbType` is used -- docs say "setting the value isn't support"?
3. How does this work if multiple statements exist in the same command?

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53268090/10984827) shows that multiple commands in a single string can be prepared together but it's not clear how this CommandText string is created.

---

Edit: I think I'm almost there but I'm not sure how to create and execute the batched the query string. Here's my naive attempt at building a batched query using a StringBuilder. This doesn't work. How do I do this correctly?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Npgsql;
using NpgsqlTypes;

class Model
{
    public int value1 { get; }
    public int value2 { get; }

    public Model(int value1, int value2)
    {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dataRows = new List<Model>();
        dataRows.Add(new Model(3,2));
        dataRows.Add(new Model(27,-10));
        dataRows.Add(new Model(11,-11));

        var connString = "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Database=dbtest1";

        // tabletest1
        // ----------
        //   id        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
        // , value1    INT NOT NULL
        // , value2    INT NOT NULL

        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO tabletest1 (value1,value2) VALUES (@value1,@value2)";
            var parameterValue1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("value1", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
            var parameterValue2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("value2", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
            cmd.Prepare();

            var batchCommand = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var d in dataRows)
            {
                parameterValue1.Value = d.value1;
                parameterValue2.Value = d.value2;
                batchCommand.Append(cmd.CommandText);
                batchCommand.Append(";");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(batchCommand.ToString());
            // conn.ExecuteNonQuery(batchCommand.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Simply capture the NpgsqlParameter returned from `Add()`, and then set its Value property:

```
var p = cmd.Parameters.Add("p", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
cmd.Prepare();
p.Value = 8;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

2) You can use `AddWithValue()` in the same way, but if you're preparing the command in order to reuse it several times, that makes less sense. The idea is that you first add the parameter without a value, then prepare, then execute it several times, setting the value each time.

3) You can prepare a multi-statement command. As things work now, all statements in the command will share the same parameter list (which lives on NpgsqlCommand). So the same pattern holds: create your command with your SQL and parameters, prepare it, and then set parameter values and execute. Each individual statement within your command will run prepared, benefiting from the perf increase.

Here's an example with two-statement batching:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tabletest1 (value1,value2) VALUES (@v1,@v2); INSERT INTO tabletest1 (value1, value2) VALUES (@v3,@v4)";
var v1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("v1", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
var v2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("v2", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
var v3 = cmd.Parameters.Add("v3", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
var v4 = cmd.Parameters.Add("v4", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
cmd.Prepare();

while (...) {
    v1.Value = ...;
    v2.Value = ...;
    v3.Value = ...;
    v4.Value = ...;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

However, if the objective is to efficiently insert lots of data, [consider using COPY instead](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html) - it will be faster than even batched inserts.

Finally, to complete the picture, for INSERT statements specifically you can include more than one row in a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO tabletest1 (value1, value2) VALUES (1,2), (3,4)
```

You can also again parameterize the actual values, and prepare this command. This is similar to batching two INSERT statements, and should be faster (although still slower than COPY).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question with a toy example highlighting the issue I'm having with creating and executing the batch command.

Comment: Don't set CommandText after you've prepared the command - the whole point is that the same SQL is executed many times (with different parameters). Simply set `parameterValue1.Value` and invoke `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: Right, but in that case won't the queries be executed one at a time? I want to send 10 at a time. Or is there no performance difference between the two in this case?

Comment: If you want to batch, your initial CommandText (which you prepare) must have several statements in it, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @ShayRojansky If you call 'prepare' on a previously 'prepared' statement will it just get ignored ... or do i have to keep track of which ones have been already prepared?

Comment: No need to keep track - Npgsql will know the statement has already been prepared, and will ignore.

Answer (score 3):

In NpgSQL 6.0 there has been the addition of [batching/pipelining](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#batching).

Here is an updated example:

```cs
await using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
await connection.OpenAsync();
    
var batch = new NpgsqlBatch(connection);
    
const int count = 10;
const string parameterName = "parameter";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var batchCommand = new NpgsqlBatchCommand($"SELECT @{parameterName} as value");
    batchCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(parameterName, i));
    batch.BatchCommands.Add(batchCommand);
}

await batch.PrepareAsync();

var results = new List<int>(count);
await using (var reader = await batch.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    do
    {
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            results.Add(await reader.GetFieldValueAsync<int>("value"));
        }
    } while (await reader.NextResultAsync());
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```